# Please help me for solving c# loop problem,

Tags: c#, .net, loops, math

I'm stuck with a problem.

I want to create program in C# which calculates entered numbers divisions, but I can not finish that program.

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1, 2, 3, 6 |
| 7 | 1,7 |
| 8 | 1, 2, 4, 8 |

etc.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Divisions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int x = 1;
            int y = input % x;
            while(x<input){
                x++;
                while(y==0){
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

I tried every loop. I have changed this code more than 15 times. I used `do while` loop, `for loop`, even I tried to use `while` and `if` at the same time, but didn't work.

Comment: You are trying the find the prime factors of an integer

Comment: Work out how you would do this manually (using Pseudo code if you want) and then convert it to C#. You need to understand the maths problem before writing the code. Tip: read about `for` loops. Also, stuff inside a loop gets executed every iteration, stuff that isn't only gets run once. You will learn much more if you work it out yourself.

Comment: These are not prime factors, just factors. I'm not sure if the asker will benefit from the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program gets stuck in an infinite loop when `y` the variable is 0, could it be that instead of while you meant using an `if`, also your `y` variable never changes because it is outside the loop.
`While` loops are very easy to create an infinite loop

I higly encourage you to try this again and not copy what I have given you.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int x = 0;
    while(x<input){
        x++;
        int y = input % x;
        if(y==0){
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Comment: You are missing an end bracket: }.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that y will be re-evaluated everytime your loop runs. It doesn't, it's only evaluated once, before the loop, so it will always have the value `input % 1`. You need to move the assignment inside the loop:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int x = 1;
while(x<=input)
{
    if(input % x==0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    x++;
}
```

I've done away with y entirely and put it as the condition for an `if`. I also moved `x++` to the end of the loop, so it is evaluated whether it's a divisor before it is incremented. And finally I made it `x<=input` in the loop condition, so that both ends of the range are considered.